# java.lang.indexOutOfBound using arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Question: Why am I getting an IndexoutOfBound error?

Background: I am writing a store app. Using a List ArrayList to store all of items passed in through a CSV file. I wrote a product obj and it is being populated correctly. I am using a cart obj I wrote to iterate though this product list to perform add and remove methods on a separate cart ArrayList. For some reason I am getting a java.lang.IndexOutOfBound error when I compare user input to the name attribute of my product object. For this I am using the .equals method from the string class.

Code Below: This is my performAdd private method for my cart object. It promts the user for a string input and then uses that to find a specific element in my list to perform the add to my local cartList. It also removes that element from the orginal list.

```
private boolean performAdd(Inventory inventory){

        // return value
        boolean success = false;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please provide the name of the item you would like to add to the cart");
        String temp = in.nextLine();

         System.out.println(temp);

        Iterator itr = inventory.productList.iterator();

        // empty product object using default
        Product prod = new Product();

        int i = 0; // index values for grabbing objects from the inventory list

        // looping through the array list of our inventory of items
         while (itr.hasNext()){

             // check to see which product has the same name as what the user said 
             if (temp.equals(inventory.productList.get(i).getName())){

                 prod = inventory.productList.get(i); // grab the product object from inventory list and assign empty product object

                 inventory.productList.remove(i); // remove this object from the inventory list

                 addToCart(prod); // call to in class method for cart

                 success = true; // change boolean return value
                }

             i++; // increment index 
         }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that productList actually has elements to iterate through? Try printing out all the elements to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Don’t mix iterators and indexing. If your are looping with an iterator, use `iterator.next()` to access the current element instead of `get(i)`. Otherwise the iterator won’t update and `iterator.hasNext()` will always return `true` (as long as there is at least one element in your list). This causes the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
2. Don’t use `List.remove` while iterating over a list. In general, you are not allowed to modify a list while iterating over it. (Otherwise a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown.) Use `iterator.remove()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the Iterator correctly. Instead of using `get(i)`, use the `.next()` function that the Iterator provides.

What your code is currently doing is:

```
Check has next; <-- always true as long as there is 1 item because your iterator is always in position 0

There is at least 1 Therefore it's true.

// stuff

Increment i

Go to top.
```

Instead, you need to update the position of the iterator, which the .next() function does.

Also, use the built in `remove()` method in Iterator to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`